# Celery: what is the reason to have acks_late=true without setting task_reject_on_worker_lost=true

Tags: python, redis, celery

After playing with some "defect" scenarios with celery (Redis being a broker for whatever it worth) we came to understanding that there is effectively no sense in setting `acks_late=true` without simultaneous setting of `task_reject_on_worker_lost=true` because the task won't be rescheduled (again, in our tests) -- task stays in the "unacked" category forever.

At the same time everybody says that `acks_late` will make the task being subject for rescheduling on the same / another worker, so the question is: when does it happen?

The official docs [say](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/tasks.html) that

> Note that the worker will acknowledge the message if the child process
> executing the task is terminated (either by the task calling
> sys.exit(), or by signal) even when acks_late is enabled. This
> behavior is intentional as…
>
> - We don’t want to rerun tasks that forces the kernel to send a SIGSEGV (segmentation fault) or similar signals to the process.
> - We assume that a system administrator deliberately killing the task does not want it to automatically restart.
> - A task that allocates too much memory is in danger of triggering the kernel OOM killer, the same may happen again.
> - A task that always fails when redelivered may cause a high-frequency message loop taking down the system.
>
> If you really want a task to be redelivered in these scenarios you
> should consider enabling the task_reject_on_worker_lost setting.

What are possible examples of "something went wrong" that don't fall into the "worker terminated deliberately or due to a signal caught" category?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reboot, power outage, hardware failure.  n.b., all of your examples assume that the prefetch multiplier is 1.

Comment: From [Celery docs](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/glossary.html#term-acknowledged), this is what happens when there's no ack for a task due to a abrupt power outage:
"Workers acknowledge messages to signify that a message has been handled. Failing to acknowledge a message will cause the message to be redelivered. Exactly when a transaction is considered a failure varies by transport. In AMQP the transaction fails when the connection/channel is closed (or lost), but in Redis/SQS the transaction times out after a configurable amount of time (the ``visibility_timeout``)."

Comment: @2ps can you elaborate? What is the impact of the prefetch multiplier on re-queuing tasks that haven't been acknowledged?

Answer (score 10):

Note that there is a difference between the celery worker process, to the child processes actually executing the tasks.
By default, when you create a celery worker, it will create one "parent" process and x number of child processes which executes the tasks, where x is the number of CPUs you have (you can read more about this in the docs, and how to configure it)

**I have tested all the different scenarios, these are my conclusions:**

acks_late is about what happens when the worker dies. task_reject_on_worker_lost is about the actual process executing the task.

For example, if I have a k8s pod running celery process: if I send sigkill (cold shutdown) to the pod, having acks_late as true will make sure that the task will be picked up by a different worker.
But, if I kill somehow the child process executing the task (go inside the pod and kill the child process for example, or if the process exits by itself somehow), the task will not be picked up even if acks_late is true.
If you set task_reject_on_worker_lost to true, the task will be picked up again.

hope that clarifies everything

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I'm wondering when task will be picked up to another worker if I send sigkill to current worker? if some task with acks_late=True causes worker exit, will task be reassigned infinitely?

Comment: Just a precision: SIGKILL does not do a cold shutdown, SIGQUIT does.
https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/latest/userguide/workers.html#process-signals