# How to monitor Celery worker and return the task back to the queue if the worker dies or is killed?

Tags: python, django, celery

##### Problem Description

I have a microservice that uses Celery for executing asynchronous tasks. I need to monitor the state of the Celery worker and return the task back to the queue if the worker dies or is killed (e.g., due to a SIGKILL signal).

I also have another instance of Celery running on the main service side.

##### Question

Is there a way to monitor the state of the Celery worker and automatically return the task back to the queue if the worker dies or is killed?

##### Additional Information

Using `visibility_timeout` is not suitable as it would require waiting for a day before the task returns to the queue, while I need it to happen almost instantly.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to achieve what you are looking for by using Celery `task_acks_late` and `task_reject_on_worker_lost` configurations, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69107860/celery-what-is-the-reason-to-have-acks-late-true-without-setting-task-reject-on) is a good explanation of how they work, or from the Celery official documentation, [here](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/configuration.html#task-acks-late) and [here](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/configuration.html#task-reject-on-worker-lost). Both parameters are also available at the task level, as can be seen [here](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/reference/celery.app.task.html#celery.app.task.Task.acks_late) and [here](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/reference/celery.app.task.html#celery.app.task.Task.reject_on_worker_lost).
For example,

```
@app.task(acks_late=True, reject_on_worker_lost=True)
def my_task(*args, **kwargs):
    ...
```

Comment: This works fine for the worker's child process, but what if the system kills the worker with the kill command, I expect the other workers to realize that the worker is not available and return the task to the queue

Comment: From my understanding, this is what is being done by the `reject_on_work_lost` flag, from the [Celery documentation](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/reference/celery.app.task.html#celery.app.task.Task.reject_on_worker_lost),

_¨Even if acks_late is enabled, the worker will acknowledge tasks when the worker process executing them abruptly exits or is signaled (e.g., KILL/INT, etc).
Setting this to true allows the message to be re-queued instead so that the task will execute again by the same worker or another worker.¨_